# Node.js Twitter API always returns 401 or 403 when trying to stream tweets

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I've been trying to use the node package Twitter to stream, and then process the tweets for further use but am, apparently, already failing at authorization because every time I do try to access the stream I get a 401 or 403 response from the server.

I've tried these two ways of authenticating

```
const Twitter = require('twitter');

const twitterAPIKey = process.env.TWITTER_API_KEY;
const twitterAPIKeySecret = process.env.TWITTER_API_KEY_SECRET;
const twitterAccessToken = process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN;
const twitterAccessTokenSecret = process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET;
const bearerToken = process.env.TWITTER_BEARER_TOKEN;

const users = [
    '2898008473'
]

const twitterClient = new Twitter({
    consumer_key:           twitterAPIKey,
    consumer_secret:        twitterAPIKeySecret,
    bearer_token:           bearerToken
});

const stream = twitterClient.stream('statuses/filter', {follow: users}, function(stream) {
   stream.on('data', function (data) {
       console.log(data);
   });

   stream.on('error', function (error) {
       console.log(error);
   });
});
```

This is the current iteration of my code, previously I've also tried running the authentication as follows

```
const twitterClient = new Twitter({
    consumer_key:           twitterAPIKey,
    consumer_secret:        twitterAPIKeySecret,
    access_token:           twitterAccessToken,
    access_token_secret:    twitterAccessTokenSecret
});
```

With no success so far. My project *has* been approved for elevated access and I even generated new keys after that just to make sure everything would work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is probably not in your Auth code.

If this app was created after mid-2022 you no longer have access to v1.1 `statuses/filter` (regardless of elevated access) as it is [being retired](https://twittercommunity.com/t/deprecation-announcement-removing-compliance-messages-from-statuses-filter-and-retiring-statuses-sample-from-the-twitter-api-v1-1/170500). Use the V2 filtered stream instead.

Comment: This happened to be the problem, yeah. Didn't find anything about it when researching the error, thanks a lot!